# How can I lock my camera Z axis rotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, axis

I am using my mouse position to rotate my camera:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

The problem is that after rotating it for a time the camera starts rotating on the Z axis as well. What should I do to lock the Z axis rotation of the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) has an optional parameter

```
Space relativeTo = Space.Self
```

so by default it is set to `Sapce.Self` so it rotates around the **local** axes of the object.

So what happens is once you look down changing the local X-axis your local Y-axis doesn't point straight up anymore but is rather pointing a bit forward now. So if you now rotate around that local Y-axis your local horizont is suddendly not aligned with the world's horizont anymore.

---

What you want to do instead (you can actually see it also in the example in the link above) is rotating around the **Y-axis in world space** but rotate around **X-axis in local space**

like this

```
[SerializeField] private float rotationspeed;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // rotate around global world Y
    transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, Space.World);

    // rotate around local X
    transform.Rotate(0, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend multiplying by the Vectors last, as floating point isn't treated as commutative. The way you have it you will be multiplying a float and a vector together 3 times, which is slower than multiplying floats together before multiplying by the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate a object in two axis the third axis will rotate by default, you can not lock this because its the fact of real world . Try this in real world 3d object rotate any two axis third will rotate automatically.If you rotate one axis other two will be fixed .
Thanks.